# What's the difference between using <script type="text/x-custom-template"> and <script type="text/template">?

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I'm creating an snipped of code to reuse on the HTML, and find 3 ways of doing it, and I'd like to know which one is better.

- `<template>`
- `<script type="text/template">`
- `<script type="text/x-custom-template">`

I've used `<script type="text/x-custom-template">` and it displays the code on my editor with no formatting styles.

Using `<script type="text/template">`  or `<template>` it does displays the code styles.

That's all the difference I see so far, but I'd like to know which one should I use (the recommended one)

`<script id="universe-condition-template" type="text/x-custom-template">`
  `<li class="universe-condition pt-3 pb-3">`
    `<p class="conditionText font-weight-bold mb-1">AND</p>`
    `<div class="delete-link d-inline-flex mr-2">`
    ....
    `</div>`
  `</li>`
`</script>`

The results seems to be the same with the 3 options, but i don't know which one should be used.

Comment: Afaik, `<script type="text/template">` or `<script type="text/html">` is just a way of defining a template in older browsers that don't know what `<template>` is.  If your browser support is enough that all your supported browsers know what `<template>` is, just use that one.

Comment: The use of an invalid MIME type as the value of the `type` attribute of a `<script>` (both `text/template` and `text/x-custom-template` are invalid [REF](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text)) is used specifically to prevent the browser from trying to interpret the contents of the `<script>` tag as JavaScript code (and subsequently throwing a runtime error due to bad JavaScript syntax.). So this basically allows you to put anything inside the script tag for future reference.

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification!

Comment: @Taplar as far as I can see, it seems like `<template>` is not supported by IE yet: https://caniuse.com/#feat=template :(

Comment: @MarielaGonzalez Given that IE has been replaced with Edge, good luck with that, :)